# Photos app on macOS doesn't sync with iCloud when Photos app on iPhone uploaded correctly

Tags: macos, icloud, photos

I don't see photos on my macOS (macOS Big Sur) Photos app but on my iPhone (iOS 14.4) there is info that all photos were "Updated Just Now".

The count of photos in the iOS app is higher than the macOS Photos app.

I've checked the free space on macOS (there is 12GB free space), also iCloud has free space (14 GB free  of 50 GB)

Other services like Calendar and Notes sync without any problem with iPhone

Answer (score 0):

I've enabled on my iPhone on Photos the option "Upload to My Photo Stream" and I restarted macOS.
Syncing on macOS Photos come back.

Probably by mistake I switched it off.

More info how it works: https://macpaw.com/how-to/my-photo-stream-icloud